# Can an iPhone app act as a server to send messages or push notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, architecture, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to write an iOS app that can act as a client *and* a server to other iPhones over the cellular data network (i.e., without a typical centralized server).  The goal is to share series of about 200 short event messages, one at a time, from the iPhone server to multiple iPhone clients by some means of notification.  Apple Push Notification service would be fine for such notifications, but there is no need to use it specifically.

I think sending push notifications from one iPhone to another is possible by connecting to `gateway.push.apple.com` from the serving iPhone as described in the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194), but I can't find anyone else discussing this approach (maybe it's too obvious?).

The reason for all this is an attempt to avoid the overhead of infrastructure.  If this isn't feasible, alternatives which minimize or avoid additional hardware are welcome.

**Requirements**:

- Communication must be [strictly] over cellular data network

  - Wi-Fi isn't available
  - Bluetooth doesn't have enough range
- Unidirectional communication with an iPhone server multicasting to many iPhone clients
- No jailbreaking
- Ideally the serving phone's battery will be able to handle this without a recharge

**Update 5/4/11 2:12 AM EST:** Just to be clear, I don't have any particular requirement to use APNs; I thought it may have been feasible in this setup, but from the discussion below, it sounds like that's not the case.  However, I'm still interested in any other system that could help me achieve the same end result with some type of message passing or similar form of communication.

Comment: Writing an apns server on iOS would be hell easy if you can figure out how to handle devices sending their push tokens back to a server. You should read the documentation and try your hand at implementing an apns server on a hosted box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically you should be able to write a iOS app that can connect to the APNS and send notifications to other devices running your applications. However, your main problem will be to actually acquire the 'tokens' of other devices. When you have a centralized server doing the job, its always online and thus, the clients can 'talk' to it via http and register them self (giving their tokens to the server in the process). Thus the server knows the client token and it can use them to send notifications to the clients via APNS.

However this is not possible in the scenario you are talking about. But this is not to say its impossible. May be you could use an email account X, to store all client tokens. Every client will send a email to this account with their token in it. So when a another 'client' want to send a notification to another client, it can find out the token by reffering to the inbox of the email account (you can cache this stuff and optimize it in a zillion ways of course).

But the point is some how a (third party(ex: email service provider)/your own) server that is online 24/7 will be involved in the process.

Let us know how you progress with this. It would be interesting to know.

Comment: I think the main problem will actually be the fact that the APNS key will be distributed with the iOS app, meaning anyone could grab it and use it however they please.

Comment: yep that would be another problem.

Comment: Interesting idea.  In a typical scenario, the iPhone server app would need to broadcast an event chain to 20-30 clients at a time.  Perhaps I could store the client tokens in a simple database on AWS or something like that such that infrastructure is minimal.

Comment: When the iPhone app is directly making the requests to APNS, one request has to be made for each device. APNS does not support batching yet, or even broadcasting. And network availability on the phone is not something you should rely on. Besides the security and network problems, it is a good idea ;)