# iPhone act as Provider to APNs (Apple Push Notifications without third party server)

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

So my client wants an app that works like this:

- one user presses a button on his device
- other user(s) get a push notification
- no third party server

So I have been looking into the [Apple Push Notification Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9) but I don't want to have a third party "provider" server.  Would it be possible for an iPhone to act as a "provider"?

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877944/can-an-iphone-app-act-as-a-server-to-send-messages-or-push-notifications) which sounds like what I want to do but I am not satisfied with the answer.  More specifically:

- Would encrypting the APNs key with another key hardcoded into the app be secure enough?  Any other ideas for dealing with that issue?
- The tokens will always stay the same for a given app for a given device, right?  If that's the case, I can deal with creating the token database.  If that's not the case, my app won't work.
- Will Apple accept such an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would encrypting the APNs key with another key hardcoded into the app be secure enough?

I believe the main issue is you'll need to deliver APNS certificate and private key with your app, and renew it when needed (on all devices). Regardless of it being encrypted or not, if it is available for your app, it might become available for attacker (by dumping its plaintext representation from memory, or by disassembling your decryption code) and make it possible to impersonate your app. So no, it is not secure.

> The tokens will always stay the same for a given app for a given device, right?

Not really. Documentation claims that *a device token is not a unique ID that you can use to identify a device. Device tokens can change after updating the operating system on a device. As a result, apps should send their device token*.

> Will Apple accept such an app?

I believe there were no precedents because of the reasons above.